# Mapbox GL JS long tap/press

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

When using Mapbox GL JS in a browser, including using the emulation mode in Chrome, the event `contextmenu` responds to a long click/tap on the map. However, on a real device this event does not fire when the user taps and holds on the map.

What is the best way to listen for long taps on the map in Mapbox GL JS?

Comment: Which device? This could be a bug or an issue worth reporting at https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues

Comment: iOS. In the emulator in Chrome the tap-hold works as expected with the `contextmenu` event

Comment: Is the issue with Chrome on iOS, or a different browser? Think you should probably report it.

Comment: I have the same issue, works fine on desktop and emulator but not on real devices (tested on chrome android 4.4 and safari IOS 10). Did you manage to resolve the issue ?

Comment: I have not found a solution yet. Might be worth filing a bug.

Comment: I am also facing issue in ios. it is working in android but not working in ios. what is solution?

Comment: Facing this issue on android & IOS. There is an open bug report here: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/10179

Answer (score 5):

Similar issue is discussed [here](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/6025).

My derived solution looks like this:

```js
    if (Browser.isIos()) {
        init_ios_context_menu();
    } else {
        map.on('contextmenu', (e) => {
            show_context_menu_or_whatever(e);
        });
    } // end if

    function init_ios_context_menu() {
        let iosTimeout = null;
        let clearIosTimeout = () => { clearTimeout(iosTimeout); };

        map.on('touchstart', (e) => {
            if (e.originalEvent.touches.length > 1) {
                return;
            }
            iosTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
                show_context_menu_or_whatever(e);
            }, 500);
        });
        map.on('touchend', clearIosTimeout);
        map.on('touchcancel', clearIosTimeout);
        map.on('touchmove', clearIosTimeout);
        map.on('pointerdrag', clearIosTimeout);
        map.on('pointermove', clearIosTimeout);
        map.on('moveend', clearIosTimeout);
        map.on('gesturestart', clearIosTimeout);
        map.on('gesturechange', clearIosTimeout);
        map.on('gestureend', clearIosTimeout);
    };
```